# Set value of datefield from DB

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a `datefield` in my form which is:

```
{
    xtype: 'datefield', 
    id : 'usap3', 
    anchor: '100%', 
    name: 'stockAsOn', 
    format: 'd/m/Y', 
    width: 199
}
```

I get a value from the DB and when I try to set the same in this field, it won't display.

```
alert(stock_as_on); //17-OCT-14
parsed_stock_as_on = Ext.Date.parse(stock_as_on, "Ymd");
Ext.getCmp('usap3').setValue(parsed_stock_as_on);
```

I tried the above code after researching through various sources, but in vain.
What should I do to display the `datefield` with the value set in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `altFormats: 'd-M-y'` to your date field. You don't need to use the `Ext.Date.parse` function because the `setValue` will work with a string. But if you want to keep parsing your date, just change the mask to 'd-M-Y'.

So:

```
{
    xtype: 'datefield', 
    id : 'usap3', 
    anchor: '100%', 
    name: 'stockAsOn', 
    format: 'd/m/Y', 
    altFormats: 'd-M-y',
    width: 199
}

alert(stock_as_on); //17-OCT-14
//parsed_stock_as_on = Ext.Date.parse(stock_as_on, "d-M-y");
Ext.getCmp('usap3').setValue(stock_as_on);
```